# Add library without gradle or maven

Tags: java, eclipse, firebase

I'm developing application backend using google app engine, using eclipse as IDE, and I want to use the google's Firebase SDK. In the integration page, Google give these options to install the backend's SDK:

We publish the Firebase Java SDK to the Maven central repository. To install the library, you can simply declare it as a dependency in your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:[3.0.0,)'
}
```

If you use Maven to build your application, you can add the following dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
  <artifactId>firebase-server-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>[3.0.0,)</version>
</dependency>
```

The backend doesn't use Gradle to build, and I'm not sure about the Maven option. Until now, I always downloaded the jars for the libraries I used

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can always manually download the jar from a central repository like [Maven Central Repository](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-server-sdk). But I would strongly recommend getting familiar with some Java build tool as it will make your life a lot easier.